# VoiceOver announcing text change OS X

Tags: macos, nstextfield, nstextview, voiceover

I have a non-editable text view (I can make it a text field, it doesn't matter). I change it programmatically when a user presses a button. I want VoiceOver to announce the change without moving the cursor. So the VO cursor stays on the textView/Field and when the text changes, just announce the change.

I'm trying to get this to work with a braille display.

I've tried posting an `NSAccessibilityValueChangedNotification` but so far I get absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same in OS X, but in iOS land, you might accomplish this by posting a `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification`.

In the OS X 10.9 SDK, it appears that there's a similar notification available in Lion and beyond called `NSAccessibilityAnnouncementRequestedNotification`. It takes a `userInfo` dictionary instead of the simple `NSString` that `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` takes, but it should do what you're asking.

Good Luck!